# Making dynamic web project (jsp,servlet) available on local wifi network

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have developed one jsp,servlet project. In which I am making some images accessible over the local wifi network. I have placed all the images under "WebContent" folder. I have deployed this dynamic project on some machine "machinex", which is connected to wifi network "localwifi". I am able to access the pages of my project from other computers( connected to "localwifi") using url : http://machinex:8080/myprojectname/mypage.html, But when I try to access same page on my android device which also connected to "localwifi" fails to get the page. Any suggestions ?

Comment: firewall? different subnet?

Comment: @Scary Wombat this is the environment, all machines are connected to "localwifi", application is deployed on one of the machine, accessible on all  machines (connected to "local wifi"), but fails to load on mobile devices connected to the same "local wifi".

Comment: Several routers offer "guest" connections to phones an tablets. Those might be able to acsess the internet, but might not be able to connect to other devices. Did you check the router? I does not matter if its a Java application or weather is wifi or lan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it is a firewall issue .

First of all you need to stop thinking in terms of why my project is not accessible on mobile ? and instead try to analyse if the computer your projects is hosted can talk to your mobile on wifi.

I would do the following.

1. Get the IP address of the computer on which project is hosted.
2. Get the ip address of the android phone on wifi.
3. While looking at the ip address itself you should be able to tell if they are on the same network.
4. If they are then try to ping(using ping command) from your computer to your mobile phone ipaddress and then do the reverse from mobile phone(ping aaps are available).
5. If both pings are not successfull then  you need to find out if any ip address is blocked on the other device.
6. If ping successfull , then try accessing the project using ipaddress of computer like http://computeripaddress:8080/myprojectname/mypage.html.

Most probably you should be able to find the problem by now.

Other things you should try

1. Try different browsers on your phone.Chrome for me nowadays shows "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" for many working websites. Try firefox or opera or another browser.

Comment: Thank you ! It worked ! I checked by pinging on the Ips, then gave IP, of the machine from "localwifi" like, http://computeripaddress:8080/myprojectname/mypage.html.

Answer (score 1):

Probably host name **machinex** doesn't get resolved. Instead you should use IP address to access your webpage.